# AWS step function Not creating exact work flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

We need to create a step function that will look like below

```
 (start sns)  
   |               ----Failed--------> Notify SNS Failed <--------End notify-
   |              |                               |Failed                            
   |              |         success               |         success            
(start) ---> [Lambda1] -------------------> [lambda 2] ------------------> (end)
```

I did following state machine  but its not as expected

```
{
  "Comment": "Work flow",
  "StartAt": "Start  SNS",
  "States": {
  "Start SNS": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
    "Parameters": {
      "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:mystartTopic",
      "Message": {
        "Input": "Step Function started lambda1"
      }
     },
     "Next": "lambda1"
},
    "lambda1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:lambda1",
      "Next": "lambda2"
    },
    "lambda2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource":"arn:lambda2",
      "Next": "End SNS"
    },
    "End Billing SNS":{
     "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
    "Parameters": {
      "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:myendTopic",
      "Message": {
        "Input": "Step Function ended "
      }
     },
     "End":true
    }
  }
}
```

It will create

(start) ---> start sns --> lambda 1 --> lambda 2 --> end sns --> end

Please help

Comment: do you want to start with SNS or lambda ?

Answer (score 0):

State machine definition should like like this for this flow

```
             ----Failed--------> Notify SNS Failed <--------End notify---|
             |                               |Failed                      |      
             |         success               |         success            |
```

(start) ---> [Lambda1] -------------------> [lambda 2] ------------------> (end)

```
   {
  "Comment": "Work flow",
  "StartAt": "Start SNS",
  "States": {
    "Start SNS": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
    "Parameters": {
      "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:mystartTopic",
      "Message": {
        "Input": "Step Function started lambda1"
      }
     },
     "Next": "lambda1"
    },
    "lambda1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:lambda1",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": ["CustomError"],
          "Next": "Notify SNS Failed"
        }
      ],
      "Next": "lambda2"
    },
    "lambda2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource":"arn:lambda2",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": ["CustomError"],
          "Next": "Notify SNS Failed"
        }
      ],
      "End":true 
    },
    "Notify SNS Failed": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
    "Parameters": {
      "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:mystartTopic",
      "Message": {
        "Input": "Step Function started lambda1"
      }
     "End":true 
     }
    
  }
}
```

Please do not mind any syntax or indentation error

Comment: This is not creating what I want where is start workflow sns why its not present in your state machine

Comment: start SNS was not present in your flow previously, did you add that now ?

Comment: Also need to know pass one lambda success paramters to other lambda and if lambda will trigger via sns then from sns to send param to the lambda 1 then lambda will again send to lambda 2 like that